# Websocket server client implementation

Tags: websocket

Is it possible to implement web socket server client where clients are located on Windows C# form application and server is located on AWS cloud with a public ip to access via connection url and node.js?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  A webSocket client or server can be on any platform that has an appropriate webSocket implementation.  Is there some reason you thought this couldn't be done?  Did you do your own research on the libraries to use and try it?

Comment: I researched earlier that I can use websocket4net to use as client for c# webs form but when I tried to connect to socket.io library on node.js, I was unsuccessfull. I couldnt figure out why websocket4net wont allow messaging over channel. where as socket.io us all based on channels.

Comment: You can't connect webSocket client to socket.io server.  You have to use webSocket client to webSocket server or socket.io client to socket.io server.